# OAuth/OpenID Connect, how do I select a key from a JWK if the token doesn't have a kid in it's header?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

Say I have two keys in my JWK but the token I am trying to verify does not have a kid in it's header. How do I determine which key to use?

Comment: Odd; as far as I can see, that only leaves the option to validate against each key until either the JWT is validated or all keys have failed.

Comment: This is normal with OAuth tokens. You grab the public key from the URL and loop thru each one. If one matches, success. If none match, error. The reason for this design is to allow private keys to be dropped and still allow previous signatures to be validated (for a while). However, including the KID in the token would not have taken much space and would save CPU time on low power devices.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other methods in the token to identify the key such as a thumbmprint (`x5t` in a JWT) or the public key itself (if you can compare it to something exchanged out of band) or a URL where the key material can be retrieved (`jwks_uri` if exchanged out of band). If there's no such reference at all you may loop over all the keys that you know are valid keys for the sender and see if one of them can be used to verify the token.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT token will contain 'alg' header and similar the JWKS has 'use' and 'alg' parameters. Instead of looping all the keys in the JWKS, you can compare JWT 'alg' header and JWKS alg to find out which key to use. In case if you have more than one key which matches both 'use' and 'alg' parameters in JWKS, loop only these matching keys to verify the token.